# How can I parse CSV files with quoted fields containing commas, in awk?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a big CSV field, and I use awk with the field separator set to a comma. However, some fields are quoted and contain a comma, and I'm facing this issue:

Original file:

```sh
Downloads $  cat testfile.csv
"aaa","bbb","ccc","dddd"
"aaa","bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
"aaa","bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

I am trying this way:

```sh
Downloads $  cat testfile.csv | awk -F "," '{ print $2","$3","$4 }'
"bbb","ccc","dddd"
"bbb","ccc","d
"bbb","ccc","dd
```

Expecting result:

```sh
"bbb","ccc","dddd"
"bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
"bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

Comment: See likely duplicate [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/3422102)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a tool that is able to properly parse CSV, such as [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv). With it, the command would look like

```sh
$ xsv select 2-4 testfile.csv 
bbb,ccc,dddd
bbb,ccc,"d,dd,d"
bbb,ccc,"dd,d,d"
```

or, if you really want every value quoted, with a second step:

```sh
$ xsv select 2-4 testfile.csv | xsv fmt --quote-always
"bbb","ccc","dddd"
"bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
"bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

Comment: Nod for selecting a proper tool for the job. Otherwise, the number of corner-cases to cover become unwieldy quick.

Answer (score 1):

Include (escaped) quotes in your field separator flag, and add them to your output print fields:

```
testfile.csv | awk -F "\",\"" '{print "\""$2"\",\""$3"\",\""$4}'
```

output:

```
"bbb","ccc","dddd"
"bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
"bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

Comment: Not getting the expected result, you are taking 2nd field quotes and comma
```
Downloads $  cat testfile.csv | awk -F "\",\"" '{print $2"\",\""$3"\",\""$4}'
bbb","ccc","dddd" >> starting double quote missing
bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

Comment: fixed the missing quote

Answer (score 1):

If `gawk` or `GNU awk` is available, you can make use of `FPAT`, which matches the fields, instead of splitting on field separators.

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS=, '{print $2, $3, $4}' testfile.csv
```

Result:

```
"bbb","ccc","dddd"
"bbb","ccc","d,dd,d"
"bbb","ccc","dd,d,d"
```

The string `([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")` is a regex pattern which matches either of:

- `([^,]+)` ... matches a sequence of any characters other than a comma.
- `(\"[^\"]+\")` ... matches a string enclosed by double quotes (which may include commas in between).

The parentheses around the patterns are put for visual clarity purpose and the regex will work without them such as `FPAT='[^,]+|\"[^\"]+\"'` because the alternative `|` has lower precedence.

Comment: [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) suggest to use `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`